# Default copy constructor

Tags: c++, destructor, copy-constructor, delete-operator, default-copy-constructor

I came across the idea of a copy constructor and using a pointer as a member variable of the class. The lecturer told me that if we use the default copy constructor to create an instance for a class with a member variable of type pointer, the default copy constructor will use the shallow copy and causing the compiler to delete the same memory space twice. But when I try it I did not find the same issue using the same code, and when I output the address of the two pointers from different instances, the output is different. I wonder if the compiler itself has adapted it to deep copy for the default copy constructer or there is something wrong with the code. Thank you!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
    
class Person
{
    public:
    Person(int age,int height)
    {
        m_age = age;
        m_height = new int(height);
        cout << "Person constructed function with param" << endl;
    }

    Person(const Person &p)
    {
        cout << "Person 拷贝构造函数调用" << endl;
        m_age = p.m_age;
        cout << "here" << endl;
        m_height = new int(*p.m_height);
        cout << "地址：" << &m_height << endl;
    }
        
    Person()
    {
        cout << "Person constructer function without param" << endl;
    }
    
    ~Person()
    {
        if (m_height != NULL)
        {
            delete m_height;
            m_height = NULL;
        }
            
        cout << "Person destructer" << endl;
    }
        
    int m_age = 0;
    int* m_height = NULL;
};
    
void test01()
{
    Person p1(18, 160);
        
    cout << "age of p1: " << p1.m_age <<", height:" << &p1.m_height << endl;
        
    Person p2(p1);
        
    cout << "age of p2: " << p2.m_age << ", height:" << &p2.m_height << endl;
} 
    
int main()
{
    test01();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"...default copy constructer will use the shallow copy..."_ but you have not used the default copy constructor and have instead provided your own `Person::Person(const Person &p)` which almost does every thing needed - it should probably copy the value (not the pointer) of `m_height` into the new class.

Comment: I know where my code was wrong now, the reason I thought they used different addresses was that instead of outputting the address of the m_height, in the code I output the address of the pointer to the data, which were of course two different addresses.

Answer (score 2):

In your copy constructor, in this statement:

```
m_age = p.m_age;
```

You assigned the value of one data member to another.

But in this statement:

```
m_height = new int(*p.m_height);
```

You did not assign the value of one data member to another.

If instead, you had written:

```
m_height = p.m_height;
```

Then two data members of different objects will point to the same dynamically allocated memory that is freed in the destructor. As a result, two objects will try to free the same memory two times.

This is what the lecturer is warning you about.  If you don't write your own copy constructor to deep-copy the dynamic object being pointed at, this shallow-copy of the pointer is the type of code that the default compiler-generated constructor will use.